# How to Connect Crystal Report to SQL server Using Code

Tags: c#

I solved Crystal report connection issue I was asking for help here and i would like to help others who facing it.

```
Form1 frm=new Form1();
CrystalReport myreport = new CrystalReport();
myreport.SetDatabaseLogon("UserName","Password","ServerName","DatabaseName");
frm.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myreport;
frm.ShowDialog();
```

this overload method takes all 4 agruments the required information for the sql connection string.
I hope that clear enough, thank you.